# Displaying notifications from a CLI app

Tags: command-line, notifications, swift

I'm new to the Apple development ecosystem. I thought I'd start with writing CLI apps in Swift (and work my way towards OS X and iOS).

Although there is no GUI involved, I want to display notifications using the native notifications API. Is this possible with CLI apps written in Swift? Are there examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a proper Cocoa app bundle to display notifications in the app. However, you can use AppleScript to accomplish this:

```
display notification "foo"
```

So with Swift, you can use NSTask:

```
NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath("/usr/bin/osascript", arguments: ["-e", "display notification \"Hello\""])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer because of the `NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath` pointer, however if this is what I have to do I may as well script it all using JavaScript per http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145732/5007